# How to express equals relation in sparql?

Tags: sparql, rdfs

I am trying to use sparql to find all French labels of words that are related to a given English word.

The query I made is something like the following:

```
SELECT ?extword ?word ?label where {
    ?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
    {?extword rdf:type ?word}
    UNION
    {?word rdf:type ?extword}.
    ?extword rdfs:label ?label filter(lang(?label)="fra")
    }
```

While it does give me the French labels of the `extword` as desired, it does not give the French labels of `word` itself.

What I need is to insert a clause to express the relation that `extword` is exactly `word`, like this:

```
SELECT ?extword ?word ?label where {
    ?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
    {?extword = ?word}
    UNION
    {?extword rdf:type ?word}
    UNION
    {?word rdf:type ?extword}.
    ?extword rdfs:label ?label filter(lang(?label)="fra")
    }
```

It turns out to be syntax error. Is it possible to also include the French labels of `word` itself, without doing another query?

To be clearer, the result I expect is the result from my first query combined with result from the following query:

```
SELECT ?word ?label where {
    ?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
    ?word rdfs:label ?label filter(lang(?label)="fra")
    }
```

Comment: UNION clauses are executed independently from each other. That's why this can't work. The solution is to use a FILTER besides the UNION pattern, i.e. `SELECT ?extword ?word ?label where {
    ?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
   
    
    {?extword rdf:type ?word}
    UNION
    {?word rdf:type ?extword}.
    ?extword rdfs:label ?label filter(lang(?label)="fra")
    } FILTER(?extword = ?word)}` Indeed, this query might be wrong because for me the whole query isn't clear so far.

Comment: What I don't understand is the purpose of the query. Can you show some sample data + the expected result?

Comment: Something like `?extword rdf:type|^rdf:type ?word` could be also used in your query to simplify it

Comment: @AKSW see http://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT+%3Fextword+%3Fword+%3Flabel+where+%7B%0D%0A++++%3Fword+rdfs%3Alabel+%22shark%22%40eng.%0D%0A++++%7B%3Fextword+rdf%3Atype+%3Fword%7D%0D%0A++++UNION%0D%0A++++%7B%3Fword+rdf%3Atype+%3Fextword%7D.%0D%0A++++%3Fextword+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+filter%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%3D%22fra%22%29%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on

Comment: The expected result are the French labels of all the `extword` as well as that of the `word`. The result of my original query are only the labels of `extword`.

Comment: @AKSW I've added an example query to be clearer.

Comment: Ok, but what I don't get is why you're trying to do `?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng. ?word rdf:type ?extword` - shark is a class, thus, it's used in object position of a triple when using `rdf:type` relation. I mean, try this query: `SELECT * {
    ?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
   
?word rdf:type ?extword
}` - it's empty

Comment: This query is probably what you want: `SELECT * {
?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
?word rdfs:label ?wordLabel .
filter(langmatches(lang(?wordLabel), 'fra'))

?extword rdf:type ?word .
?extword rdfs:label ?extLabel
filter(langmatches(lang(?extLabel), 'fra'))
}`

Comment: And if you really want the inverse relation (although empty), as I said, use the property path `rdf:type|^rdf:type` in the query: `SELECT * {
?word rdfs:label "shark"@eng.
?word rdfs:label ?wordLabel .
filter(langmatches(lang(?wordLabel), 'fra'))

?extword rdf:type|^rdf:type ?word .
?extword rdfs:label ?extLabel
filter(langmatches(lang(?extLabel), 'fra'))
}`

Comment: @AKSW I want to extend a list of existing words, to be used as search keywords, so the user can find related documents using the original words as well as the extended words.

Comment: @AKSW Your last query works for me! Why not post it as an answer.

Comment: The query before should also work. In fact, usually you have `INSTANCE rdf:type CLASS` - shark is a class in Yago, thus, it won't occur in a triple `Shark rdf:type CLASS`

Comment: @AKSW Shark here is just an example, actually there are many other words, I'll query them one by one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183930/discussion-between-ngy-and-aksw).

Comment: I think you're falling victim to [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Perhaps if you describe what you're actually trying to achieve, and where you're starting, we can provide better advice.